# Populate Table in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, footable

I am using fooTable jQuery plugin as date grid in jQuery mobile. I have list of data I need to populate in the table. Initially with filtering and cell formatting. First I want to populate data in the table. I am using an external .js file to keep JavaScript separately.

HTML5 code, "$.App.initGridView" is not calling from "data-init" tag. Why isn't it working?

```
<div data-role="view"  data-title="Platform" onloadeddata="$.App.initGridView" data-init="$.App.initGridView">
        <table  class="footable table" id="my-table">
            <thead >
            <tr data-theme="b">
                <th >Ticket#</th>
                <th >Date</th>
                <th data-hide="phone">Operator Name</th>
                <th data-hide="phone">Lease Name</abbr></th>
                <th >Tank#</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
initGridView: function () {
         var rtList = $.App.tempDB.getTicketList();
         // I want to populate table here  
}
```

Comment: since you are using JQM, why don't you use the JQM [table](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/table-column-toggle/) with [filterable](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/filterable/) widget?

Comment: I have 8 columns to display in table, as I think fooTable gives more flexibility than JQM table

Comment: then you should modify your question title and tags. :-)